# What is a good choice/comparison for a wireless router for 40 machines

Tags: router

I know that Cisco 851 routers have worked well for half a dozen machines, but that was wired connection only.

I really have almost no experience in this area.

We will be managing the router remotely.

There will be a single IP address on the outside and a NAT on the inside.

Comment: If you need 40 WiFi clients on at the same time, you'll need some sort of business grade APs with a central unit. Even the good ones can only handle about two dozen, so you'll need two (or more) if they're all going to be active at the same time. Best idea is probably to call a local consultant who is an expert in Cisco gear.

Comment: What are APs?__

Comment: Oh, never-mind, I remember: Access Points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up calling Cisco Small Business and they were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ubiquity Gear.

www.UBNT.com

Ubiquity runs a large number of the networks behind the folks @ www.Wispa.org 
[image: Wireless ISP Association]

We use their gear as well for backup microwave links for the datacenter when all the fiber into the facility fails.

We move well over 100mbps over the links AND they can handle Numerous connections - in fact we push an entire /20 over them

A good unit that could support 40 clients easily is the Air Router from Ubiquity http://ubnt.com/airrouter
[image: Air Router from Ubiquity]

There are other options - but either one of these would work great.
We are not affiliated with Ubiquity in any way... just love their gear.

Comment: This looks too much like an ad. Perhaps remove the images and tell us exactly what exactly makes this better than other product. And we are not talking about microwave in this question.